# v-if on style block

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Is it possible to use `v-if` on `style` block, like so?

```
<style lang="scss" v-if="pinkTheme">
.ac-textfield 
{
    background: hotpink;
}
</style>
```

I tried this and it's not working (the `v-if` directive is ignored). I know that I could do this:

```
<div class="ac-textfield" v-style="{ background: pinkTheme ? 'hotpink' : false }"></div>
```

However, this will quickly become difficult to maintain if I want to modulate more than one style using the value of `pinkTheme`. Right now, I'm using CSS selectors to achieve the desired effect:

```
<template>
    <div class="ac-textfield" :class="{ pinkTheme }">
    </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
.ac-textfield
{
    //...
}

.ac-textfield.pink-theme
{
    background: hotpink;
}
</style>
```

However, I don't like this solution very much (I want to achieve greater separation between my themes, and I want the browser to only have to load one theme at a time). Is there any way to make something like the first code block work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cannot work as `scss` must be compiled to `css` - and this is done at *build-time*. `v-if`, though, is executed/interpreted at ***run-time*** only.

What would kind of work, is to include the `style` block in the `template` part of your single file vue component, but note that you can only use CSS, not SCSS, in there. That has the obvious downside of getting rendered alongside each of the component instances.

Your approach of using conditional CSS classes actually is the correct approach, so you should definitely stick to that.

Comment: I thought it might work, because each `style` block is compiled into a webpack module, right? What stops Vue.js from simply loading and unloading these modules based on the condition? I realise that doing this directly would introduce a dependency on webpack, but doesn't the idea make sense?

Comment: @laptou, I think your idea makes a ton of sense. I have a similar need. The best thing I found was the [condition-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/condition-loader) webpack loader. If you can get past the low usage and Chinese instructions, it seems perfect (for my use case, anyway). Hopefully you'll find it useful too.

Answer (score 0):

v-if is used for conditional html rendering and v-if accept the getter function that should return either true or false. You can't use v-if with style.